# Maven choosing either stanford-corenlp models or non-models, not both

Tags: maven, stanford-nlp

The documentation says to include:

```
    <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unfortunately, when trying to build an RPM, the assembly plugin outputs:

[INFO] [INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
[INFO] [INFO] lib/stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar already added, skipping

and we only get the first jar, not the models one, in the final result.

I know this is something on our end, since it seems to be working fine for other people, but does anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong? Searching for anything related to maven skipping the "classifier" part hasn't worked since the word classifier is used in so many contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually found the answer to this--in our assembly.xml, we had this:

```
<dependencySet>
  <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
  <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
  <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
  <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
  <unpack>false</unpack>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependencySet>
```

The outputFileNameMapping value was overriding the default, and missing the segment that would include the classifier: `${dashClassifier?}`

The current Maven default is: `${module.artifactId}-${module.version}${dashClassifier?}.${module.extension}`

so we just removed the outputFileNameMapping declaration and it fixed it.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html